# Issue with image resize using intervention in laravel 4

Tags: php, image, laravel, image-resizing, intervention

I was working to configure intervention to work on my laravel 4 project as I need to resize the images I upload, I did everything perfectly as explained everywhere and autoloaded the package in my vendor and inserted the necessary lines in config/app and composer files.

BUT I still can't do the job as I'm receiving an error when I try to resize. The error says (couldn't call make() in intervention/Image::make). Apparently, the problem is that the make method doesn't exist or can't be called, I went to the Image class but never seen the make method. Any suggestoins?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction on http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel?

Comment: @Mithredate yes I have both installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!! 
What was missing is the 'use' statement at the top of my controller :

```
     use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the GD Library or the imagick PHP extension installed on your server?

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

Comment: I have both installed